# Warning: calling polyEqual

Tags: sml, smlnj

Can somebody please explain, what does this warning means?

```
stdIn:18.35 Warning: calling polyEqual
```

and why do I have "a and not 'a in the following statement:

```
val alreadyVisited = fn : ''a * ''a list -> bool
```

this is my function:

```
fun alreadyVisited(v, []) = false
    | alreadyVisited(v, x::xs) = if(x=v) then true
        else alreadyVisited(v, xs);
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`'a` means "any type", while `''a` means "any type that can be compared for equality". Since your `alreadyVisited` function compared `x` and `v` using `=`, `x` and `v` need to have a type that supports comparing them for equality, so you get the type `''a`.

The warning means that you're comparing two values with polymorphic type for equality.

Why does this produce a warning? Because it's less efficient than comparing two values of known types for equality.

How do you get rid of the warning? By changing your function to only work with a specific type instead of any type.

Should you care about the warning? Probably not. In most cases I would argue that having a function that can work for any type is more important than having the most efficient code possible, so I'd just ignore the warning.

Comment: I get the same warning in the, perhaps simplified, case: `fun some_fun((*stuff*)) = [];` likely because the compiler cannot infer the type of an empty list. Putting, say, a string in the list makes the warning go away.