# Why is the signature different for these two Standard ML functions?

Tags: sml

I am trying to implement a function that checks whether or not a list is empty (similar to `List.null`).

This has signature `val isEmpty = fn: ''a list -> bool`:

```ml
fun isEmpty ls =
  ls = []
```

This has signature `val isEmpty = fn: 'a list -> bool`:

```ml
fun isEmpty [] = true
  | isEmpty _ = false
```

Why are the signatures different for these two functions although they do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big hint to what is happening here is that (in SML/NJ) the first definition triggers `Warning: calling polyEqual`. It is based on a list comparison, but in SML that only makes sense for equality types. Your first definition fails when you do something like

```
isEmpty [1.0, 2.1];
```

whereas the other two definitions have no problem with that. Thus -- the three definitions *don't* "do the same thing". They almost do, but not quite.

See [Warning: calling polyequal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4322661/4996248) for more on that warning.

Comment: In Poly/ML and Moscow ML, there is no warning. In Moscow ML, `isEmpty [1.0, 2.1];` gives no error.

Comment: @Flux I was using SML/NJ.Whether or not there is a warning, the signature on the first definition says that it only applies to lists of equality types. Perhaps in Moscow ML `real` is implemented as an equality type. If so, this is non-standard. You should be able to find another example (e.g. a list of functions) for it to throw an error.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was in testing the function only on int list, char list, and string list inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that the first version is more powerful than the second. The equality operator has the following type, which will constrain the type signature of the first version:

```
$ sml
Standard ML of New Jersey (64-bit) v110.99.2 [built: Thu Sep 23 13:44:44 2021]
- op =;
val it = fn : ''a * ''a -> bool
```

The `''a` constraint propagates to the enclosing function definition.

The second version doesn't make use of that operator because it doesn't need to, it only needs to look at the shape of the list, not its constituent elements. We can desugar it to make this more obvious:

```
fun isEmpty list =
  case list of
  | nil => true
  | _ :: _ => false
```

It's clear here that it doesn't care about the elements, whereas the other does care, potentially, even if it doesn't in your particular case. For example:

```
fun isPalindrome list =
  list = List.rev list
```